# running discounted price in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

This is my first post so pardon any missing information. I do have dataset like this below

**Dataset:-**

[image]

My expected final output should be like this

**Final Output:-**

[image]

Basically I would like to iterate over Discounted price and apply last discounted price to next year

For example in 2019 , NYC Budget is $10,000 and Discount is 0.05 so Discounted Price is $9,500. Next year discount becomes 0.64 which should be calculated on $9,500, which is $3,420 and in 2021 , 0.04 which comes out to be $3,283 as final discounted price for NYC.

I need to code it in Python using pandas data frame. I think I need to write For loop and then IF inside it . But struggling so far.

Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) the function to obtain the total discount amount for all the years for a particular city. Then use [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html) over the `Budget` column groups to get the first row in the group with the rows indexed as the original dataframe. This holds true since `"Groupby preserves the order of rows within each group."` is a guaranteed behavior.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Year': {0: 2019, 1: 2020, 2: 2021, 3: 2019, 4: 2020, 5: 2019},
'City': {0: 'NYC',  1: 'NYC',  2: 'NYC',  3: 'Edison',  4: 'Edison',  5: 'Princeton'},
'Budget': {0: 10000, 1: 10000, 2: 10000, 3: 5000, 4: 5000, 5: 2000},
'Discount': {0: 0.05, 1: 0.64, 2: 0.04, 3: 0.35, 4: 0.06, 5: 0.45}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

g = df.groupby("City")

disc_prod = g['Discount'].apply(lambda x: (1-x).prod())
budget = g['Budget'].first()
result = disc_prod * budget

print(result)
```

```py
City
Edison       3055.0
NYC          3283.2
Princeton    1100.0
```